# Class variable access from top level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a complete beginner to Ruby. I am working on Lesson 45 of Learn Ruby the Hard Way currently and am creating a game similar to Zork and Adventure.

I have created a structure where I am creating 'scenes' in different files and requiring all the scenes in one file where I have an engine/map that ensures if the current scene does not equal 'finished' that it runs 'X' scene's 'enter' method.

However I have two issues:
1) I keep getting a error saying 'Warning class variable access from top level'
2) Even though the script is running I get

```
ex45.rb:30:in `play': undefined method `enter' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) from ex45.rb:59:in
```

The following is all of my code from each file. My apologies if it's a long read, but I would love to know why I am getting these two errors and what I can do to fix them.

Ex45.rb:

```
require "./scene_one.rb"
require "./scene_two.rb"
require "./scene_three.rb"

@@action = SceneOne.new
@@action_two = SceneTwo.new
@@action_three = SceneThree.new

class Engine

    def initialize(scene_map)
        @scene_map = scene_map
    end

    def play()      
        current_scene = @scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = @scene_map.next_scene('finished')

        while current_scene != last_scene
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = @scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
        end

        current_scene.enter()
    end
end


class Map

    @@scenes = {
        'scene_one' => @@action,
        'scene_two' => @@action_two,
        'scene_three' => @@action_three
    }

    def initialize(start_scene)
        @start_scene = start_scene
    end

    def next_scene(scene_name)
        val = @@scenes[scene_name]
        return val
    end

    def opening_scene()
        return next_scene(@start_scene)
    end
end

a_map = Map.new('scene_one')
a_game = Engine.new(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

scene_one.rb:

class SceneOne

```
  def enter
    puts "What is 1 + 2?"
    print "> "

    answer = $stdin.gets.chomp

    if answer == "3"
        puts "Good job"
        return 'scene_two'
    else
        puts "try again"
        test
    end
  end

end
```

scene_two.rb

```
class SceneTwo

    def enter
        puts "1 + 3?"
        print "> "

        action = $stdin.gets.chomp

        if action == "4"
            return 'scene_three'
        else
            puts "CANNOT COMPUTE"
        end
    end

end
```

scene_three.rb

```
class SceneThree

    def enter
        puts "This is scene three"
    end

end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer to your first question**:

You need to move the class variable definitions inside your `Map` class to get rid of these warnings:

```
Ex45.rb:5: warning: class variable access from toplevel
Ex45.rb:6: warning: class variable access from toplevel
Ex45.rb:7: warning: class variable access from toplevel
```

So, your `Map` class would look like this:

```
class Map
    @@action = SceneOne.new
    @@action_two = SceneTwo.new
    @@action_three = SceneThree.new

    @@scenes = {
        'scene_one' => @@action,
        'scene_two' => @@action_two,
        'scene_three' => @@action_three
    }

    def initialize(start_scene)
        @start_scene = start_scene
    end

    def next_scene(scene_name)
        val = @@scenes[scene_name]
        return val
    end

    def opening_scene()
        return next_scene(@start_scene)
    end
end
```

**To answer your 2nd question:**

You are getting `undefined method 'enter' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` because your `current_scene` becomes `nil` at some point and then you try to call: `current_scene.enter()` i.e. `nil.enter` and it fails with that error message.

To solve this problem, you have to make sure you always have some value in your `current_scene` i.e. make sure it's not `nil`.

I think, you can just remove `current_scene.enter()` line from the end of your `play` method in the `Engine` class. So, your `Engine` class will look like this:

```
class Engine
    def initialize(scene_map)
        @scene_map = scene_map
    end

    def play()      
        current_scene = @scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = @scene_map.next_scene('finished')

        while current_scene != last_scene
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = @scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
        end

        # current_scene.enter()
    end
end
```

And, you won't get that error anymore.

Comment: Could it be this line? `@scene_map.opening_scene()` it is being called from the play function in the Engine class but `opening_scene()` is defined in the Map class. But I am not all that clear on the @ or @@ variable thing

Comment: No, that's not the issue because `@scene_map` is an object of the `Map` class. So, that's fine. Problem is, `current_scene` is `nil` at the end of the `while` loop in the `play` method of the `Engine` class as I specified in my answer's 2nd part.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Both solutions worked! 

I also remembered I had a while loop where I stated if the current scene != last scene (i.e. 'finished'). So this way 'current_scene' would either have to equal basically scene_map.opening_scene OR 'finished'. So once I added my 'finished' file and current_scene couldn't = nil I stopped getting the error. 

Thanks again!

Comment: @KarthikSoravanahalli glad it helped you solve your problem :)

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam gotcha. thats why i was asking more than trying to answer, lol. you already got my +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know:

```
@@y = 20
p Object.class_variables

--output:--
1.rb:1: warning: class variable access from toplevel
[:@@y]
```

And:

```
class Object
  def self.y
    @@y
  end
end

puts Object.y

--output:--
20
```

But:

```
class Dog
  @@y = "hello"

  def self.y
    @@y
  end
end

puts Dog.y     #=>hello
puts Object.y  #=>What do you think?
```

The output of the last line is the reason that class variables are not used in ruby.  Instead of **class variables**, you should use what are known as ***class instance variables***:

```
class Object
  @y = 10   #class instance variable

  def self.y
    @y
  end
end

puts Object.y


class Dog
  @y = "hello"

  def self.y
    @y
  end
end

puts Dog.y     #=> hello
puts Object.y  #=> 10
```

A class instance variable is just an @variable that is inside the class, but outside any def.  And instead of there being one **@@variable** that is shared by all the subclasses, each subclass will have its own **@variable**.